# Navigation Bar back button text colour reverts to default

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationbar, uifont

I have some code in my app that is supposed to change the colour of the navigation bar font. The problem is that while I have been developing the code, I've been adding code to do this but I haven't been checking to see what parts I actually need. I am wondering if this is contributing to an issue I've been having.

Basically, occasionally (I haven't figured out exactly what the cause is) when I open the app, the colour of the back button text reverts to the default blue colour.

Here is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 24)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

    let appearanceTab = UITabBarItem.appearance()
    let appearanceNav = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    let attributesTabBar = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 11)]
    appearanceTab.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesTabBar, forState: .Normal)

    appearanceNav.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 25)]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x009051)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x009051)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.newBlueColor()
}
```

I've tried removing different parts of the code, but I haven't been able to identify the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add following code to **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff) // White color
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x034517) // Green shade

// change navigation item title color
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: this does not change the color of back button, it remains same as default color. Does we have any other solution ?

Comment: For "setting color of back button solution" , we need to add  >> "UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes( [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)" <<

Answer (score 0):

I gave a solution someone else once, I saved the code.  Play with it this way some.

```
var attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.greenColor(),NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30)]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: That's actually the code I have in the first line. It works great normally, but for whatever reason it sometimes seems to get overwritten/doesn't function and I wasn't sure if some of the other code was conflicting with it?